# Posting with Jquery - Show page after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

So usually when I want to submit a form, I either do it via Ajax or just submit it normally.
Submitting via Ajax will only return the result (response) and will not display the POST page, while submitting the form takes you to the POST page with the POST variables available.
What I'm wondering is to create POST variables with Jquery submit the form, but I want to display the action page after submitting.
One way would be to have  in HTML and use hidden  to pass the variables, this is how I currently do. Is there a way to achieve this via Ajax, using something like this:

```
var data = {'id': 20};
var posting = $.post( "pay_card", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the callback for the jquery.post like this

```
$.post( "pay_card", data, function(data) {
   // this function is executed on success, so here you can redirect the user action page
   window.location.href = '/some-action';
});
```

thats the not fancy way, there are some cool libraries like [jquery ajax form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)
also the code above can be optimized by promises

Cheers

Comment: Cheers for your answer. So this will redirect to /some-action, but will it also hold all of the POST variables intact?

Comment: yes, the redirect will happen after the ajax finishes, so you variables will be intact until that. do you need them in the other /some-action page ?

Comment: Actually I want to redirect to the action (pay_card) and have the values intact in there for processing.

Comment: so you need to consider send your parameter through the get. like this /pay-card?param=someting&foo=bar